# Mac OS X Internet Sharing creates ad hoc network

Tags: macos, wifi, internet-sharing

Every time I try to use Internet sharing `Ethernet` --> `Wi-Fi`, my Mac seems to create an ad hoc network, rather than using the currently connected wifi network.  How do I make my Mac share to the current wifi network, and have a static IP?

Alternate wording: How to share the ethernet-based Internet connection of a Mac with a computer that is part of router-based wireless LAN without Internet connection?

Router is an AT&T modem/router that has been repurposed for LAN/wifi.  The Mac is connected to an Apple Airport Time Capsule via ethernet, and the AT&T router via wifi.  I need to share the ATC internet to the AT&T router's LAN network, while giving the Mac an IP address of `192.168.1.1`.

Comment: I remember giving an answer to your previous question on this matter – unfortunately, I was wrong. To share an Ethernet-based Internet connection with a Wifi-connected machine, the built in Internet sharing of OS X only works by creating an ad-hoc network, a.k.a. computer-to-computer connection. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18704?locale=en_GB I'm going to delete my old answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: Aha.  Well so much for that.  Post it as an answer that it just don't work (or give me a hack/mod) and I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe reword your question e.g.  "How to share the ethernet-based Internet connection of a Mac with a computer that is part of router-based wireless LAN without Internet connection?" + give the exact Wifi router model.